# Running application that opens relative file path from anywhere

Tags: bash, filesystems

I have application that at startup opens file relative to executable (this file path are statically compile into program binary and I cannot modify it). I want to create an alias to it that can be run from anywhere in the system without first "cd" into it's folder to make sure file will be found.

Is that even possible ?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If the program requires you to `cd` to the directory, and the program cannot be changed, you cannot run that program without `cd`-ing to that directory. It is as simple as that.

You can, however, start a second shell, that `cd`-s to the directory and executes the program. When the program is finished, the second shell terminates and, because your main shell did not `cd`, you're still in the same place.

As a quick example:

```
$ alias ptmpdir="bash <<< 'cd /tmp ; pwd'"
$ ptmpdir
/tmp
```

This, as pointed out by Kamil Maciorowski in the comments puts the command in the STDIN of the shell. This works OK if the program does not use STDIN, like `pwd` in the example, and it does not check for errors.

```
alias lstmpdir="bash -c 'cd /tmp && ls' ls"
```

checks for errors and provides the correct exit-code if the `cd` fails:

```
$ alias ptmpdir="bash -c 'cd /hop && ls' ls"
$ if ptmpdir ; then
> echo yes
> else
> echo no
> fi
ls: line 0: cd: /hop: No such file or directory
no
```

If you want to pass arguments to the command as well, the alias get messy and even harder to understand. In that case. a function would be better:

```
$ hop(){ bash   -c 'cd /tmp && exec ls "$@"' ls "$@" ; }
$ hop
7iCipjf8J7         eh._2700550        in.clean.1285563                          tmp-ntt.xpi
MozillaMailnews    <rest deleted>

$ hop -lrt
total 56496
drwxrwxr-x 3 ljm      ljm          4096 Nov  5 17:28 gimp
drwxrwxr-x 2 ljm      ljm          4096 Nov  5 18:14 jna-107183
-rw------- 1 ljm      ljm             0 Nov  6 00:17 config-err-Ol5gyl
drwx------ 2 ljm      ljm          4096 Nov  6 00:17 ssh-FqqWxHh4jhu8
<rest deleted>
```